# make a responsive button that stays in the same position on top of an image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I want to put a button on top of a responsive image but not in the center, and I want it to stay at the same position on top of another button in the image.
Here is my code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rvr21jq6/):

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="img">
      <img src="http://www.playful.ma/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/img.png" class="0">
  </div>

  <div class="overlay">
   <h4>My Button</h4>
</div>
```

this is the css

```
.container{

  width: 100%;

}

.overlay{
  position:absolute;
  top:70%;
  left:60%;
  padding:10px;
  background:white;
  border-radius:10px;
}


.img{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

I want the `.overlay` div to stay in the same position on top of the blue button in the image when resizing the browser.
thank you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rvr21jq6/1/

Comment: @linktoahref thank you but this doesn't work if the image is responsive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get pretty close by making the image a background image and using relative positioning with a viewport unit font size.

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 31.875%;
  height: 0;
  background: url('http://www.playful.ma/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/img.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

h4 {
  position:absolute;
  top:70.5%;
  left:34%;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.4vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <h4>My Button</h4>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Michael Coker , this work great . i have another question what if i want to use an image instead of text . i mean an image that stays at the same position when resizing the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Use this css to get you in the right direction.

```
.container{
  width: 100%;
  position: relative
}

.overlay{
  position:absolute;
  top:63%;
  left:50%;
  padding:10px;
  background:white;
  border-radius:10px;
}
```

notice the container is `position:relative;` and the overlay is `position:absolute;`

Comment: this code doesn't make the overlay div on the same position on top of the image but thank you .